# Implementing shutdown command from scratch

Tags: bash, shell, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

```
root ~$ shutdown
-sh: shutdown: not found

root ~$ shutdown -h now
-sh: shutdown: not found
```

None of the commands are working . I think I need to link the command from scratch. Can anybody guide?

```
uname -a
```

gives

```
2.6.35.3 #49 PREEMPT Wed Jun 11 20:03:43 IST 2014 armv5tejl GNU/Linux
```

Comment: please add information about which operative system you are using

Comment: try `/sbin/init 0` (as root)

Answer (score 1):

Try to call the command with complete path: `/sbin/shutdown`

moreover on most systems it is a root only command, so you should call it from root user (I am seeing the $ at the end of command prompt, so I am guessing you are not root)

Other commands you can try are presented [here](http://www.binarytides.com/linux-command-shutdown-reboot-restart-system/); 
or you can use the `init 0` command always as root user.

Writing the shutdown code is a last costly resort only if all the other alternatives fail.

Comment: there is no such file present under /sbin/shutdown